load build context error in docker-compose.yml file
Below is my docker-compose.yml file
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=** 
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongopw
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mongodb/data
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
  auction-svc:
    image: ***/auction-svc:latest
    build:
      context: .                 
      dockerfile: src/AuctionService/Dockerfile  
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - RabbitMq__Host=rabbitmq
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=postgres:5432;User Id=postgres;Password=**;Database=auctions 
      - IdentityServiceUrl=http://identity-svc
    ports:
      - 7001:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq

below is my Dockerfile inside AuctionService
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80


COPY Bidify.sln Bidify.sln
COPY src/AuctionService/AuctionService.csproj src/AuctionService/AuctionService.csproj
COPY src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj
COPY src/GatewayService/GatewayService.csproj src/GatewayService/GatewayService.csproj
COPY src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj
COPY src/IdentityService/IdentityService.csproj src/IdentityService/IdentityService.csproj


RUN dotnet restore Bidify.sln


COPY src/SearchService src/SearchService
COPY src/Contracts src/Contracts
WORKDIR /app/src/SearchService
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/src/out

 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "SearchService.dll" ]

Getting error load build context  when I execute this command : docker compose build auction-svc
I working on microservice app. Inside src I have services. Inside of my Bidify app I have docker-compose.yml file.  Ican't find the solution to this problem
